# AngularJS: returning data from a function and assigning it to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

I am new to angularjs, and I am trying to return the data from a function to another function, and store it in a variable.

```
$scope.myNameValidate = function(name){
    $scope.friendsList = $scope.getAllFriends(name);
    console.log("data", $scope.friendsList);
}

$scope.getAllFriends = function(name){
    friendService.getAllfriends(name) 
    .then(function(data){
        //success
        console.log(data);
    }, function(err){
        //error
    })
}
```

I want to store all the objects in a variable but I get undefined as result.

output in console

data undefined

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to know the [Angular promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

This issue related to [Asynchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) operation.

You can fix it with proper `then`able chaining.
You can do it in this way.

```
$scope.myNameValidate = function(name) {
    $scope.getAllFriends(name)
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.friendsList = data;
            console.log(data);
        }, function(err) {
            //error
        });

}

$scope.getAllFriends = function(name) {
    return friendService.getAllfriends(name)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Why its' undefined?**

Your function `$scope.getAllFriends()` is not returning anything witch can set data to $scope.friendsList.

```
function myFunc(){
 var i = 5;
}
var myVar = myFunc();

myVar will not have value 5.

function myFunc(){
 var i = 5;
return i;
}
var myVar = myFunc();
```

> In angular even if it's asynchronous data when you set to $scope as
>   soon data has arrived angular will update your view and scope.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use async callbacks this way. In your particular case you should set $scope.friendsList inside the success callback.

```
$scope.myNameValidate = function(name) {
    $scope.getAllFriends(name);
}

$scope.getAllFriends = function(name) {
    friendService.getAllfriends(name) 
    .then(function(data) {
        $scope.friendsList = data;
        console.log("data", $scope.friendsList);
    }, function(err){
        //error
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.myNameValidate = function(name){
$scope.friendsList = $scope.getAllFriends(name)
   .then(function(data){
    //here is your data
   })
  .catch(error){
   //Error
   }
console.log("data", $scope.friendsList);
}

$scope.getAllFriends = function(name){
  var promise = friendService.getAllfriends(name) 
   .then(function(data){
     return data;
  }, function(err){
    //error
 })
 return promise;
 }
```

This is asynchronus call thats why you got undefined